how to apply prefix- config to tailwind cdn before it runs in userscript?
// ==UserScript==
...
// @match        */*
// @require      https://cdn.tailwindcss.com
// @run-at       document-end
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    tailwind.config = {prefix: 'tw-'};
    console.log('tailwind.');
})();

tailwind.config = { prefix: 'tw-' }; will be applied only after tailwind runs.
I also tried dynamically loading script with setting config with .onload, it doesn't help. Setting config before loading also not working.

You can embed literal JS code using @require data:, like this:
// ==UserScript==
...
// @require      data:,tailwind={config:{prefix:'tw-'}};
// @require      https://cdn.tailwindcss.com
// ==/UserScript==

Warning! All # must be replaced with %23 in this data URL.
